# How to compare two objects of different types where one inherits the other's type

Tags: c#, oop, compare

I have two self-made objects. PersonalizedCard and BaseCard. I want to compare these two for equality.

The PersonalizedCard inherits BaseCard class.

BaseCard has **Color** and **Number**.

PersonalizedCard has **Color**, **Number** and **Name**

(Both of them have at least 20 different variables in them, which I left out for clarity)

I tried casting them both back and forth to check for equality, but haven't found a proper solution yet.

`var oldCard = UserCards.Cast<IUserCardObject>().FirstOrDefault((card) => card.PersonalCardObject == CurrentCard);`

Here CurrentCard is a BaseCard and I'm comparing it to card.PersonalCardObject which inherits the BaseCard class.

I want to compare BaseCard and PersonalizedCard on Color and Number. If they're both a BaseCard, this should be possible I feel.

How do I do this?

Comment: So are your 20 different variables defined on the BaseCard OR in BaseCard and PersonalizedCard separatedly? How do those different properties map to each other if latter case?

Comment: They're defined in BaseCard and PersonalizedCard inherits them. PersonalizedCard only has a few extra variables that are not on BaseCard.

Comment: Then overriding the Equals method and checking all properties related to equality is necessary.

Comment: Most everything you need to know about overriding `Equals()` can be found in the marked duplicate. Including the pros/cons of allowing instances of two different types to be considered equal to each other, as you're proposing here (hint: it's almost never a good idea). I would recommend instead you consider implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>`, or even just using a `Comparison` delegate, depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

`Obj1 == Obj2` will compare the reference, not the content.

If you want to have some custom comparison between 2 objects, you can implement the interface [`IEquatable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.8)

```
public bool Equals(BaseCard other)
{
    if (other == null)
        return false;

    /*
     * Add as many property comparison as needed
     * This will define what makes 2 objects equal
     */
    return this.Color == other.Color
           && this.Number == other.Number;
}

 public override bool Equals(Object obj)
 {
     if (obj == null)
         return false;

     BaseCard cardOther = obj as BaseCard;
     if (cardOther == null)
         return false;
     else
         return Equals(cardOther);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Number; // could be something else
}

/*
 * This allows you to do card.PersonalCardObject == CurrentCard
 * without comparing references
 * This is optional and not necessarily wanted
 */
public static bool operator == (BaseCard card1, BaseCard card2)
{
    if (((object)card1) == null || ((object)card2) == null)
        return Object.Equals(card1, card2);

    return card1.Equals(card2);
}

// Same as above, this is optional and not necessarily wanted
public static bool operator != (BaseCard card1, BaseCard card2)
{
    if (((object)card1) == null || ((object)card2) == null)
        return ! Object.Equals(card1, card2);

    return ! (card1.Equals(card2));
}
```